# Find relative velocity for hand movement.Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, velocity, direction, calculus

The problem is for body movement. So i have a function that must consider the velocity of joint(3d point) j4 relative to joint j3(3d point) and assumes the value one
iff the component of this velocity in the direction determined by the line segment from j1(3d point) to j2(3d point) is above threshold θ. The said velocity component can also be viewed as the signed, one-dimensional velocity of joint j4 relative to the plane determined by a normal vector (given by j1 and j2) and the anchor joint j3.

for example,i want to check if right wrist is moving upwards.So j4=right wrist , j3=chest , j2=chest,j1=belly . I must find the relative velocity to j3 of j4 , at the direction of the line from j1 to j2. How can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a math/physics question than a programming question. Once you've figured out the math behind it (hint: look up "[relative velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity)"), the code to implement it will be quite simple.

In your case, what you want is the velocity of j4 relative to j3 (i.e., `v(j4 | j3)`). This is given by:

```
v(j4 | j3) = v(j4) - v(j3)
```

Then I'll leave it as an exercise to find the velocity in the direction of j1->j2.

Comment: Thanks chuckN, but i knew that relative velocity is that.Sorry that i didn't mention it. The problem i have is the direction.How can i find the component of the velocity in this direction? the direction changes in every frame(velocity is checked for a sequence of frames). I want the math explanation in order to change it to code.

Comment: What you're looking for is the "orthogonal projection" of `v(j4 | j3)` onto the line (j1 -> j2). [Here's a tutorial on how to do that](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Orthogonal_Projection_Onto_a_Line), but you should also be able to find it in any introductory linear algebra book.

Comment: I believe that must be the solution, i will test to see if i have the correct results.Than you a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. First of all i find the velocity of j3 and j4 for each axis -- x,y,z --. Then i find the relative to j3 velocity of j4 for each axis. Then because i have the normal vector n(xn,yn,zn) for every frame ,i find for each frame of the sequence   a scalar value. That means  i find a variable v(i)=dot(velocity_j4_j3(:,i),normal(:,i) , where i is the frame and : means x,y,z components. The result gives the value one only for the correct direction. The direction that points the normal. Before that the value was one for the correct and the opposite direction.